# Android Intents.SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT always show only the Uri string

Tags: android

I need to show/interact with a new contact before create it, and I need a simple way to add it to the phone contacts.

this is the code I use:

```
String contactPhone = "33333333";   
Uri contactUri = Uri.parse(String.format("tel: %s", contactPhone));
Intent addContactIntent = new Intent(
                ContactsContract.Intents.SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT, contactUri); 
addContactIntent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, "FirstName" );
addContactIntent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.COMPANY,"CompanyName");
addContactIntent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE,contactPhone);
addContactIntent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL,"contact@email.com");
startActivity(addContactIntent);
```

and this is the result. The problem is that the Intent show me only the Phone instead all the info added.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION if you want to interact before create it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, getName());
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.COMPANY, getCompany());
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL, getEmail());
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, getPhone());
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL, getAddress());
startActivity(intent);
```

This works pretty well. I hope this will help you.

Comment: I don't want it in edit mode. I need a way to interact with the contact and save it only if necessary.
With this way I can't call the number until i saved.

Answer (score 0):

This site (http://wiresareobsolete.com/2011/10/simplifying-interaction-with-contacts/) shows and gives examples) that SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT can only trigger off "tel" or "mailto"/email for searches.